# What does ord(ab) state w.r.t. lower/upper bound if ab = ba

Tags: group-theory

I have following question about a problem in algebraic structures:

Let (G,*) be group and a,b are elements of G with ord(a) and ord(b) are finite.
Which arguments can we find about ord(ab) regarding lower/upper bound if ab=ba.

Thank you in advance for useful answers !

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Using $ab=ba$, first prove that $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$. This should help you give the upper bound for $\mathrm{ord}(ab)$. The lower bound should be clear if you take $b=a^{-1}$.

Comment: thx for this hint but how can I imagine an upper bound of an ord(ab) which is defined as a minimum of a set? The lower bound is clear now.

Comment: @mojo $a^nb^n=e$ if $a^n=e$ and $b^n=e$...

Comment: @5xum ... Although it's worth pointing out that the converse doesn't hold, for instance in your lower bound example.